# add https for subdomains using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have two subdomains like  `schools.mydomain.co.uk`  and  `admin.mydomain.co.uk`,I need to add `https://` for all request url for both two domains,I have change my `.htaccess` like as follows.These two subdomains  pointing to the same root folder.
but gettiong an error **"This webpage has a redirect loop"**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.mydomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://admin.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^schools\.mydomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://schools.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking whether they are already being accessed using `HTTPS`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(admin|schools)\.mydomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```